# Where is stored temporal data in Google colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I used this command to import this csv file directly from a link:

!wget https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/boot/acme.csv -P drive/app

In Google Colab there's a tab in the left side (an arrow), when you display there are 3 sub-tabs (Table of contents, Code snippets and Files), inside Files, there is a folder named "sample data". When I execute the code a new folder is created ("drive", inside "app" folder and inside the csv file "acme")

Where is this data stored?

It seems the data is just temporary stored because the next day I open the notebook is gone.

Something similar happened when I cloned a github repository with this code:

!git clone https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml.git

The data was appeard (when I clicked refresh) in a folder containing the repository. It never was stored in my drive of Google Drive or anything.

In some website recommended to type "%cd" in the notebook to change the directory, but the output just was: "/root", and since I don't have a clue where the data dir is I can't go back unless I restart the notebook.

Is there any documentation where I can learn more about the different folders and dynamic of the data and codes to access to it?

Answer (score 4):

The [I/O example notebook](http://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) is a useful reference.

The disk on Colab backends is ephemeral and is reclaimed shortly after your session ends. It's best to store permanent data in Drive. There's [a recipe in the example above](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA) describing how to mount your Google Drive files in  the backend.